# Advance Data copying

Tags: vba, excel

[image: [enter image description here][1]Going to try my best to explain here.]

I have got a database with Product codes on, descriptions, supplier code and agreement (Which is a yes/no Column).

In a nutshell Within column D I need a code which can read the data in column C and then depending on that supplier code it will then copy a yes or a no  in column D.

Is there any way to write this rule in visual basic? or Will i have to input the data manually?

Example
Supplier code -  YES / NO
CVVV001       =   NO

Comment: Please provide a mimimal code example of the columns you're talking about. Organized, concrete code examples help the community understand your question and increases the chances of a good and helpful answer.

Comment: There probably is, but you do not provide enough data to give a more definitive answer. For us to be able to help you best,  I would suggest you familiarize with how this site works by taking the [Two Minute Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP pages for information as to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can't have a formula in column C that puts a value in column D. Is that a typo or do you really mean that? Also, what does determine yes or no? What is the logic?

Comment: Why is `CVVV001 = NO`? What is the logic?

Comment: I have to look up the data on another document to find out weather or not it is a yes or a no.

So the plan is to find a quicker way. What I want to do is list all the product codes and then their values will equal to a yes or no. This data will be then copied over to column D.

Comment: This is a job for a worksheet function, not VBA. You can use a function like MATCH() to check if CVVV001 is found in the other sheet. The function will fill your column C. Then you can use Copy/Paste Values to convert the formula into text.

Comment: Have you got an example of the match function? Bearing in mind this document is over 7000 rows long. hence why I though visual basic would be best to replicate the data.

Answer (score -1):

7000 rows is peanuts. Your problem is that you don't know about Excel's built-in formulas. I suggest you look into [Match()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) and maybe [Vlookup()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1). These functions can look up a value in a different sheet/workbook and return the row number or an attribute of the found match. Just because you don't know that these things exist does not mean that you need VBA to achieve your goal. Simply take some time to learn more about Excel.

Comment: I just like writing the code instead and wondered if i could my copy and paste and set a  couple of rules. I will have a look into match. Have you got an example I could use or? Vlookup won't be needed as it will be new data which doesn't exist.

Comment: Why are you asking for examples? Did you read the articles? They come with examples. You say `I just like writing the code instead` which means that you don't know about Excel's super-fast built-in functions and you prefer to re-invent the wheel with slower, self-made VBA. I guess it's a matter of personal preference, but you will never match the calculation speed of built-in functions with your home-made VBA routines. A little upskilling into what Excel can do out of the box would boost your productivity by miles.

Comment: Okay guys, I will give this a try thanks for your time